# jsfiddle width miscalculation?

Tags: css, html, jsfiddle

problem: have a photo-gallery with css:

```
ul.photo-grid { 
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 840px;
}

ul.photo-grid > li.photo {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 25%; 
  min-width: 210px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;

  vertical-align: baseline !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

with html like this:

```
<ul class="photo-grid">
   <li class="photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="img/150x200.jpg" class="photo-img"/>
        <span class="photo-title">a girl</span>
      </a>
  </li>...
```

interestingly works fine in chrome, firefox, opera, ie: shows 4 perfect columns, but it doesn't in jsfiddle(shows 3 columns)! Any clues why it can happen?

Comment: do you have to publish your site on `jsfiddle`??? why bother about it if its rendering well on major browsers?? :)

Comment: Did you include all the CSS files on your site into the JSFiddle as well? Sometimes a "background" CSS file, like a CSS reset, matters a lot to layouts.

Comment: @NoobEditor i have to present the result there

Comment: @Terry there is no other css files

Comment: Show us the fiddle, or it didn't happen ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not give any space between `<li>`. As you added the rule `display:inline-block`. That give a little space between two `<li>`. Write like this.

```
<ul class="photo-grid">
   <li class="photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="http://tracy.titanserver2.com/tph/getPhoto.php?uid=5358029&num=1&type=3" width="150" class="photo-img"/>
        <span class="photo-title">a girl</span>
      </a>
  </li
    ><li class="photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="http://tracy.titanserver2.com/tph/getPhoto.php?uid=5358029&num=1&type=3" width="150" class="photo-img"/>
        <span class="photo-title">a girl</span>
      </a>
  </li
    ><li class="photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="http://tracy.titanserver2.com/tph/getPhoto.php?uid=5358029&num=1&type=3" width="150" class="photo-img"/>
        <span class="photo-title">a girl</span>
      </a>
  </li
    ><li class="photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo-link">
        <img src="http://tracy.titanserver2.com/tph/getPhoto.php?uid=5358029&num=1&type=3" width="150" class="photo-img"/>
        <span class="photo-title">a girl</span>
      </a>
  </li>
    </ul>
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrtj2Lao/) or your [fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/ghjL7qdn/3/). Look the `html` and `css`.

Comment: ah damn! i forgot that spaces will mess up that much! thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah! that's weird. They should have break the list. And the solution I gave here is one of many. There are others, like setting the font-size:0; You should experiment with them. Or else simply use float:left instead of display:inline-block. :-)

Comment: `float:left` doesn't fit here - pictures can be horizontal or vertical, but aligning to baseline of the sign below. used to use font-size: 0 before, yes=)